# SQLFRORM.grid pagination to not refresh the whole page without the use of the LOAD function?

Tags: ajax, web2py

Is there a way in web2py for SQLFRORM.grid pagination to not refresh the whole page without the use of the LOAD function?

Answer (score 0):

In general, refreshing something on the page with data from the server without reloading the whole page will require an Ajax call (or websockets, or an iframe). The easiest way to do that in web2py is probably to use the `LOAD()` helper, though you could set up the Ajax manually as well.